# Elasticsearch error when trying to register Percolator with geo_distance filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch with marvel/sense plugin to create index of shapes with dot type and then register geo_distance filter in percolator:

```
PUT shapes
{
  "mappings": {
    "dot": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point",
          "fielddata": {
            "lat_lon": "true",
            "precision": "1cm"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT shapes/.percolator/in_sight
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "200km",
                "location" : {
                    "lat" : 40,
                    "lon" : -70
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this yields the following error:

```
{
   "error": "PercolatorException[[shapes] failed to parse query [in_sight]]; nested: NullPointerException; ",
   "status": 500
}
```

any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it's all about syntax which is hard to guess with elasticsearch:

```
    #Create mappings for dot and ellipse types
PUT shapes
{
  "mappings": {
    "dot": {
      "properties": {
        "tag" : { "type" : "string" },
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point",
          "fielddata": {
            "lat_lon": "true"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ellipse": {
      "properties": {
        "tag" : { "type" : "string" },
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point",
          "fielddata": {
            "lat_lon": "true"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

#Register geo_distance with percolator
PUT shapes/.percolator/in_sight
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "250km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 30,
            "lon": 31
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

#Query doc against percolator.
POST shapes/ellipse/_percolate
{
  "doc": {
    "tag": "t3",
    "location": {
      "lat": 30,
      "lon": 30
    }
  }
}
```